# Is there a function that exists that will let me cycle through a set of variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Essentially I have an SQL query that has a where clause that is 

`WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE) = 2012)`

There is a lot of other code behind the query. I know I can do a Union, which works fine but I end up with massive queries when all I want to do is change say the above date to 2011 or 2013. Is there an easier way to format this to do the equivalent of multiple variables without repeating the entire statement in a UNION query?

Comment: If all you need is a differing date, you can use WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE) IN (2011, 2012, 2013) or WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE) BETWEEN 2011 and 2013. An "OR" clause is also a possibility, but often perform poorly.

Comment: That's not quite what I was after, part of this SQL query makes a calculation (the amount of minutes used by a company in a year for example). If I use the IN etc then I get all the results totalled. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining the IN clause with a GROUP BY

```
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE) IN (2011, 2012, 2013)
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE)
```

You may also need to add other values select to the group by clause, but not the aggregated values.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose you know any easy way to get the year it is referring to in the group by into a different column? The above works fine and I get three results but I am unable to identify which one is 2011, which one is 2012 and which one is 2013!

Comment: Are you selecting the datepart in the final output? If so, then that should identify the year. Otherwise, it is difficult to answer such a question without seeing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `IN` operator? As in

```
WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE) IN (2011, 2012) )
```

Comment: No - the select query I am trying to simplify calculates a total for say 2012. If I use the IN function then it totals all those years which I don't want. I want a result on row 1 for 2011, then a result on row 2 for 2012 etc. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: If you need to filter the data, you still need the in by. However, you are referring to the GROUP BY clause.